# How to fetch all contacts using Outlook/ Microsoft Graph REST API

Tags: node.js, outlook, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I'm working on a Node App.

The requirement is fetch to fetch Outlook contacts once the user is authenticated.

The API is https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts

I get contacts in batches of 10. There's a *@odata.nextLink* parameter to fetch the next 10 contacts, but in the middle, after collecting 50-70 contacts, I get this error.

The token cannot be invalid as its validity is for 1 hour.

This is the error that I get

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
    "message": "Unable to initialize RPS",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "81b399f0-ca5d-4e4d-b696-0052531f607d",
      "date": "2016-06-30T12:23:13"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to replicate this using https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/graph-explorer as well?

Comment: I tried, but this is the error that I get AADSTS50020: User account 'abc@gmail.com' from identity provider 'live.com' does not exist in tenant 'Microsoft' and cannot access the application '8a3eb86b-8149-4231-9ff3-3c50958ea0fd' in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account.

Comment: I think that means you need to refresh your expired access token using the provided refresh token?